# Oracle Query - Get only strings in the select field

Tags: sql, oracle, string, numeric

Maybe this sounds a little bit crazy, but I need to come up with a query to retrieve only letters out of an alphanumeric field.

For example:

**TABLE**
1234ADD
3901AC
1812OPA
82711AUU

**RESULTS EXPECTED**
ADD
AC
OPA
AUU

Thank you!

Comment: What happens for something like `ABC123EFG` what is the expected result for that?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: According to the configuration of our system that's never going to happen. The string will always be at the end, how ever the length of the string can't be identified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you only want to remove numbers. You can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) for that in 10g or 11g:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( your_column, '[0-9]*', '' ) FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE('1234ADD 3901AC 1812OPA 82711AUU', '[0-9]', '')
FROM    dual
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

SELECT TRANSLATE('1234ADD 3901AC 1812OPA 82711AUU', 'A1234567890', 'A') FROM dual;

and in general see: http://www.psoug.org/reference/translate_replace.html

Comment: I wrote this a bit hurriedly and don't have an Oracle instance handy to test it, sorry. This is why I added the link...

Comment: corrected. If the third parameter to TRANSLATE is NULL it always returns NULL.